# How to get the test coverage using Grails?

Tags: grails, testing, test-coverage

I wonder if there's a Grails way to find my test coverage in my Grails application?

My app is built using Intelli-J and spock testing.

If there's also a way to show some graphs it would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [Test Code Coverage](http://grails.org/plugin/code-coverage) plugin that will report coverage for you, however it [currently does not support](https://github.com/beckje01/grails-code-coverage/issues/11) forked mode. Aside from that limitation it's a very useful plugin.

Comment: I assume `cobertura` is the only free test coverage tool. There is [clover](http://grails.org/plugin/clover) which I do not think is free but comes with a FREE 30-day evaluation Clover license. Nevertheless, `cobertura` suffices the purpose very well.